# Amazon Quicksight API UpdateDataSet doesn't update the attribute DataSetUsageConfiguration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to update a DataSet using JAVA code in a JUNIT test class.
I get the dataSet updated except the attribute "dataSetUsageConfiguration".
I wonder if there is a condition/ limitation while updating dataSets on quicksight.
Here's My code :

```
`@Test
public void ModifyDataSet() {
    List<InputColumn> inputColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    List<TransformOperation> dataTransforms = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, PhysicalTable> physicalTableMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, LogicalTable> logicalTableMap = new HashMap<>();
    inputColumns.add(InputColumn.builder().name("id").type("STRING").build());
    dataTransforms.add(TransformOperation
        .builder()
        .projectOperation(
            ProjectOperation
                .builder()
                .projectedColumns("id").build()).build());
    physicalTableMap
        .put(
            "KEY",
            PhysicalTable
                .builder()
                .relationalTable(
                    RelationalTable
                        .builder()
                        .dataSourceArn(
                            "my_data_source_ARN")
                        .schema("my_schema").name("name")
                        .inputColumns(inputColumns).build()).build());
    logicalTableMap.put(
        "key",
        LogicalTable
            .builder()
            .alias("alias")
            .dataTransforms(dataTransforms)
            .source(
                LogicalTableSource.builder()
                    .physicalTableId("physicalTableID").build()).build());
    // the attribute doesn't get updated (except when we change it through the quicksight interface )
    DataSetUsageConfiguration dataSetUsageConfig =
        DataSetUsageConfiguration.builder().disableUseAsImportedSource(true)
            .disableUseAsDirectQuerySource(true).build();

    UpdateDataSetRequest updateDataSetRequest =
        UpdateDataSetRequest.builder().awsAccountId("awsAccountId")
            .dataSetId("dataSetId")
            .physicalTableMap(physicalTableMap).logicalTableMap(logicalTableMap)
            .dataSetUsageConfiguration(dataSetUsageConfig).name("name")
            .importMode("importMode").build();
    UpdateDataSetResponse response = this.quickSightClient.updateDataSet(updateDataSetRequest);

    DescribeDataSetResponse reponse =
        this.quickSightClient.describeDataSet(DescribeDataSetRequest.builder()
            .awsAccountId("awsAccountId").dataSetId("dataSetId")
            .build());
    
    Assert.assertEquals(reponse.dataSet().name(), "name");
    Assert.assertTrue(reponse.dataSet().dataSetUsageConfiguration()
    .disableUseAsDirectQuerySource());
    Assert.assertTrue(reponse.dataSet().dataSetUsageConfiguration()
    .disableUseAsImportedSource());`
```

The test class fails since the Assert is wrong.
I also tested that using the cli and the same issue.
i only get to update this parameter when im using the quicksight interface.